Function in google sheets that will display a drop down if a cell is populated
Could anyone provide some assistance on writing a function a function in google sheets such that, when a value is populated in one of the rows in column A, that a drop down list appears in same row in column H.
The dropdown will be the same for everyone who populates column and only has the values Yes, No and Not sure.
I can see things on who to do this using xlookup and others, but I really want this to be a function so people can't access it result in them messing it up as I'll deny access permissions to the functions.
I'm really struggling on this and that gets returned is conditional lookups which isn't what I want in this case, and it should only appear when populated others if it is empty, or populated then deleted then it should clear.
If anyone can provide a start, that would be great as I like to try and learn myself, but I just can't find a starting point for this.
Thanks very much

Would you be fine with using Google Apps Script to accomplish what you'd like to do? I believe Google Sheets formulas might not be suitable for what you explained.

Related question on "Google Docs Editors Help": Can I hide dropdowns for blank corresponding cells?.

Related question (StackOverflow): Create a Chips Dropdown in Google Sheet using Apps Script with 3 answers.

If this sample output is what you'd like to do, @user1663003, then the first question tagged should be able to help you out. Also, in my opinion, this Stack Overflow post's answer is also similar to your situation.
